# internet problems after uninstalling VS Ultimate 2010RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After I uninstalled VS 2010 RC, the browsers don't have access to internet but Skype works fine.
Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps VS 2010 configured your proxy? Check Control Panel -> Internet Options. Network tab and see if you need to clear the proxy field.